# Do your officers as captains of another ship inherit your stats?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

If I set one of my officers as a captain of another ship, is it my character stats (Sailing, Accuracy, Cannons, etc.) that govern how well they can sail and fight or does the game only use their personal stats?

This is a very confusing aspect of the game since officer bonus are reflected as your character's stats. For example, I may be a 1 in combat but if I have an officer with his own rating of 10 then I am also considered a 10.

You can only set one officer to captain another ship but there are more stats needed than a single captain will generally have that are required to sail another ship. This is what is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is always the skill of the individual captain of the ship that determines how well they can handle the ship. This is why officers accumulate XP and can be leveled up.

This is true for enemy ships as well, and has been the case across all of the Akella pirate games I have played (Sea Dogs 1, Sea Dogs 2 aka PoTC, and Sea Dogs: To Each His Own).

Unfortunately, I cannot find any source to cite except my own experience.